Read Auth Token from Response Headers in Flutterflow Custom Auth
I'm making a mobile app using Flutterflow with Odoo as backend.
The authentication API from Odoo returns the Auth Token in the headers as (set-cookie) not in the body of the response.
I'm trying to read/store that token but I can't get access to the headers (I only get the content-type header).
What's strange is that the headers are shown while testing but not in runtime.

All Tutorials and documentation explains how to read/store the token if it exists in the response body, but in my case, the token is in the headers.
